# How to setup structure of a site with multiple sections with different language requirements section wise

Tags: seo, subdomain, multilingual, subdirectory

I need to know the best way to setup structure for a site having multiple sections (Articles & Property) with each section having different language requirements.

- 1) Article section:  It contains all the infromation under different categories like lifestyle, health , sports etc. It is in single language (Norwegian)
- 2) Property Section: It list downs all properties of Spain. It requires 3 languages support (English, Norwegian, German).

I did some research on best way to setup multiple section of site (subdomain vs. subdirectory) and found that subdirectory having good advantage over subdomain setup. But I didn't find any specific details for the scenario where multiple sections having different requirements on languages.

So need to know if I place property section as subdirectory with 3 languages support, will it be harmful for SEO? If yes what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So need to know if I place property section as sub directory with 3 languages support, will it be harmful for SEO? If yes what is the best way to do this?

No, it will not be harmful for SEO if you proceed properly. You could implement the following structure:

```
http://example.com/property1/en/
http://example.com/property1/fr/
http://example.com/property1/it/
```

Then, you need to use the `hreflang` tag to link translated content (more details in a [post](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/internationalization-multi-language-seo-checklist.html) I maintain).

Comment: Thanks JVerstry for the quick response. I am more concerned about Article section. I am new to SEO so not sure that does google expect main domain(thus Article section content) to be in 3 languages as we have for property? . yes structure will be like as you have shown above. Also I checked the hreflang post and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: You can set the language to Norwegian in the article section, but if your text is Norwegian, Google will detect it automatically. You don't need to worry about the article section from an SEO perspective.